# Display Custom Pricing labels on WooCommerce Cart based on user role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I was just wondering if anyone has a solution for this problem I am currently having. I am actually trying to print a customise price on the shopping cart for my users who are accessing my online store. Below are the conditions which I plan to set.

user who are not logged in -> No Discount, not suppose to see the customise pricing display on my shopping cart page.

user who are logged in as "customer" user role -> No Discount, not suppose to see the customise pricing display on my shopping cart page.

user who are logged in as "paid_customer" user role -> Discount applied, suppose to see the customise pricing display on my shopping cart page.

Currently only users which are not logged in and "paid_customer" user role have their pricing display working correctly but not for "customer" role. Not sure if i am identifying the customer role correctly over here.

Below is the hook which I am using for this condition:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', function ( $price, $values, $cart_item_key ){

        global $woocommerce;
        $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
    
    if (!is_user_logged_in() || (in_array( 'customer', (array) $user->roles ))){
        
        return $price;
        
    }else{
        
        foreach($items as $item => $values) {
            echo "Discounted Price : " . get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , ('_sale_price', true);       
            return $price;  
        }   
    }

}, 10, 3);
```

---

**Edit:**

My pricing discounts are already managed by [Advanced dynamic pricing for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-dynamic-pricing-for-woocommerce/) plugin, based on my custom user roles, so I don't need to worry about the price output anymore.

See my code answer below, based on @LoicTheAztec accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should mention in your question which plugin you are using, as questions / answers on StackOverFlow are for the hole community and not just for you.

Your code has some mistakes and can be simplified:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'filter_wc_cart_item_price', 10, 3 );
function filter_wc_cart_item_price( $price, $values, $cart_item_key ){

    // For 'paid_customer' user role when sale price is defined
    if ( current_user_can( 'paid_customer' ) && $sale_price = get_post_meta( $values['product_id'],'_sale_price', true) ) {
    
        // The custom formatted sale price
        $price = sprintf( __("Discounted Price : %s"), wc_price( $sale_price ) );
    }
    return $price;
}
```

It should work.

---

An edit to your answer code that is incorrect **as the data in filter hooks needs always to be returned**, but not echoed:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'filter_wc_cart_item_price', 10, 3 );
function filter_wc_cart_item_price( $price, $values, $cart_item_key ){

    // For 'lifetime_member' user role when sale price is defined
    if ( current_user_can( 'paid_customer' ) ) 
    {
        $price = __("Members Price (5% Off): ") .  $price;
    } 
    elseif ( current_user_can('customer') ) 
    {
        $price = __("Normal Price: ") .  $price;
    } 
    return $price;
}
```

This is the correct and working way.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, thanks for the advise regarding about how to ask questions in future. I am actually using Advanced Dynamic Pricing Plugin from AlgoPlus [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-dynamic-pricing-for-woocommerce/) to specify discount structure for my users. I have tested your code, strangely I still had to use echo to print my text out in the shopping cart In order to display my text. I will share what i did in the following tab. Your code made the validation for differentiating my user roles work.

Comment: @wjyeshealth  I have added an edit to my answer based on your answer code… please take a look.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, thanks and noted on the revised answer. I tested it and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this hook instead "woocommerce_before_calculate_totals"

```
add_action("woocommerce_before_calculate_totals", "set_product_price");

function set_product_price($cart_obj) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    foreach ($cart_obj->get_cart() as $item) {
         if (!is_user_logged_in() || (in_array( 'customer', (array) $user->roles ))){
               $item['data']->set_price(20);
         } else {
               $item['data']->set_price(15);
         }
    }
}
```

In that way you no need to handle price during checkout and place order process.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply,  from the looks of the provided code it looks like there is a price definition for the cart, I already have that handled by a plugin i am using before item arrives on the shopping cart, i just need to present non sales price to users which are not logged in and also users with the customer user role. Can we still print prices using the provided code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to accomplish what I wanted *(thanks to @LoicTheAztec answer)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'filter_wc_cart_item_price', 10, 3 );

function filter_wc_cart_item_price( $price, $values, $cart_item_key ){

    // For 'lifetime_member' user role when sale price is defined
    if ( current_user_can( 'paid_customer' )) {
    
        echo "Members Price (5% Off): ";

    } elseif (current_user_can('customer')){
        
        echo "Normal Price: ";
        
    } 
    
    return $price;
}
```

My pricing discounts are already managed by [Advanced dynamic pricing for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-dynamic-pricing-for-woocommerce/) plugin, based on my custom user roles, so I don't need to worry about the price output anymore.